# C++ difference between copy constructors and move semantics

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Why should I use copy constructor based on move-semantics? I mean I can use non-const reference and do the same: take data from the object without copying. Or no?

Comment: When returning a non static object created in a function for example?

Comment: It is unfortunate that the "move constructor" was not instead called "suck the guts out constructor".

Comment: You cannot use a non-const reference on a temporary.

Comment: No wait. Looks like you want a copy ctor with move semantics. Why?

Comment: I can't tell if this is a honest question or just trolling

Comment: What if you want access to both options? Then it's pretty good to have both a copy constructor and a move constructor.

Comment: Here is a detailed description of what happened before when we gave a type a copy constructor with a non-const reference: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, you can - auto_ptr tried it, for example - but it doesn't work very well: for example, you cannot put objects with such a destructive copy into standard containers, because standard containers might need a copy that doesn't destroy the original. It would be surprising if e.g. insert destroyed the source object, but on the other hand, there are cases (say when the source is a temporary) when moving makes perfect sense. So C++, as usual, allows both cases (insert is overloaded for copy and move) and allows (some would say "forces") you to choose between them.